# What is the bitwise xor of an interval?

Tags: algorithms, integers

Let $\oplus$ be bitwise xor. Let $k,a,b$ be non-negative integers. $[a..b]=\{x\mid a\leq x, x\leq b\}$, it is called a integer interval.

What is a fast algorithm to find 
$\{ k\oplus x\mid x\in [a..b]\}$ as a union of set of integer intervals.

One can prove that $[a+k..b-k]\subseteq \{ k\oplus x\mid x\in [a..b]\}$ by showing that $x-y\leq x\oplus y \leq x+y$.

**Edit:** I should specify the actually input and output to remove ambiguity.

Input: $k, a, b$.

Output: $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2,\ldots,a_m,b_m$. Such that:

$$
\{ k\oplus x\mid x\in [a..b]\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^m [a_i..b_i]
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an efficient solution based on BDDs

1. Find $n$ such that $k,a,b < 2^n$. Create $n$ boolean variables, one for each position in an $n-bit$ number
2. Write out a boolean formula representing every number in that interval. For example, if $n=4$ (so that we are only considering possible inputs in $[0..15]$), then the interval $[2..4]$ can be written as $\neg x_0 \wedge ((x_1 \wedge \neg x_2 \wedge \neg x_3) \vee (\neg x_1 \wedge x_2))$ --  there is a $0$ in the $8$'s position, and either the next three bits read $100$, or the next two bits read $01$. Note that this is equivalent to partitioning the interval into subintervals aligned with powers of $2$.
3. Represent the boolean formula as a BDD
4. Similarly, write $[k..k]$ as a boolean formula. Use standard BDD algorithms to XOR the two BDDs.
5. Read the intervals out of the BDD. For example, if $n=5$, and we take the path in the BDD corresponding to setting $x_0=1,x_1=0,x_2=1$, and find that we have reached a true leaf (i.e.: a five-digit binary number that starts with 101 is in the set no matter what its lower two digits are), then the interval $[20..23]$ is in the set.

Depending on the application, you might want to leave the set as a BDD rather than reading it out back into intervals, as the BDD representation may be much more compact.

There is also a more elementary and direct solution. Note that XOR'ing by $k$ is equivalent to sequentially XOR'ing by each bit of $k$. Break $k$ into bits, and break $[a..b]$ into subintervals aligned with powers of two, and see what happens to each subinterval. You can work this out, and implement it efficiently using segtrees, but I expect that it will be equivalent to the BDD solution, which is faster and allows for the use of standard libraries.

**Analysis**

Analyzing BDDs is slightly tricky, but I'll have a go.

$[a..b]$ can be represented using at most $2\lceil\log(b-a)\rceil$ power-of-2-aligned subintervals. I'm not sure how to properly show it, but visualizing the resulting BDD, we see it will have a sort of "triskelion" structure, with size $O(\log(b-a))$.

Let $n=\max(a,b,k)$. XORing each subinterval by $k$ will preserve the subinterval, but may move it. Since each subinterval takes $O(\log n)$ space to represent  and there are $O(\log n)$ of them, this lets us bound the size of the resulting BDD as $O((\log n)^2)$. I believe this gives us a $O((\log n)^2)$ bound on the entire operation, but don't quote me on that -- the runtime is proportional to the size of the intermediate BDDs, and I'll have a bit more thinking to do to determine what happens there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one straightforward algorithm. I'm not sure what the worst case running time is, but it is at most $O(n\log^2 n )$, where $n=\max(a,b,k)$.

1. Compute the list $[k\oplus a,\ldots,k\oplus b]$.
2. Split the resulting list into *obvious* intervals, by merging adjacent entries whenever they form an interval, and creating a new interval when they don't.
3. Sort the resulting list of intervals. (This takes potentially $O(n\log n)$ steps, where each comparison is $O(\log n)$.)
4. Merge adjacent intervals.

Here is the algorithm in Haskell:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.List

-- implements step 2
split (a:as) = split_ (a,a) as
    where split_ (c,d) [] = [(c,d)]
          split_ (c,d) (e:list) | e == d + 1 = split_ (c,e) list
                                | otherwise  = (c,d) : split_ (e,e) list

-- implements step 4
merge (a:as) = merge_ a as
    where merge_ (c,d) [] = [(c,d)]
          merge_ (c,d) ((e,f):list) | e == d + 1 = merge_ (c,f) list
                                    | otherwise  = (c,d) : merge_ (e,f) list

intervals k a b 
  = merge $ sortBy (\(a,b) (c,d) -> compare a c) $ split $ map (\x -> xor k x) [a..b]
```

Comment: Using a general-purpose sorting algorithm, this will take the full $O(n\log n)$. There will be no nontrivial intervals upon XOR'ing by $1$. Of course, this list has a special structure (it will look like e.g.: [1,0,3,2,5,4]), and can be sorted in linear time.

It is more accurate to call the running time pseudo-supralinear, as the input list is not written out in full. Its actual running time is $O(n^n)$

Comment: @JamesKoppel: I don't see that I'm only sorting a list of length $n$ and I only do this once. All other steps are $O(n)$.

Comment: Sorry; accidentally posted comment unfinished.

Comment: I don't see how it will be $O(n^n)$. I don't know what pseudo-supralinear time is. Even if there are no non-trivial intervals, the worst case scenario is that I will have $n$ singleton intervals in the list at the end of step 3.

Comment: I think James was trying to say the input is only 3 integers: $k, a$ and $b$. I updated my question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I see. My algorithm runs in time dependent on $b-a$.

Comment: Your runtime analysis is missing a $\log b$ factor, to account for the time it takes to compute $k \oplus x$, to compare two elements of $[a,b]$, etc.

Comment: @DaveClarke I think the bound $O(n \log n \log b)$ holds, where $n=b-a+1$. Step 1 is $n$ steps, step 2 is $O(n)$, step 3 is $O(n \log n)$, and step 4 is $O(n)$, where each step is $O(\log b)$ (although you wouldn't bother in practice, if $k > b$, you can take the high-order bits of $k$ sight unseen if your integer representation doesn't require you to copy them), right?

Comment: @Gilles: I simplified, as $b=O(n)$ (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to the nice answer by @JamesKoppel but it is too large for a comment:

I don't think that the size of the BDD for $[a \ldots b]$ is $O(\log (b-a))$ because even to test if the $n$ Boolean input variables are equal to a fixed constant requires linear size BDD size in the number of variables, i.e. here $O(\log n)$. Similar to your idea in 2., it is possible to show that the size of the BDD for $[a \ldots b]$ has also linear size and can be efficiently constructed (i.e. in linear time according to the BDD size), see e.g. [here](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~woelfel/paper/topsort/index.html) for the construction and proof idea.

According to the running time: You have one XOR operation on BDDs of size $O(\log n)$. The running time for a XOR operation (and also the size of the resulting BDD) is in the order of the product of the sizes of the involved BDDs, i.e. overall we have a running time of $O(\log^2 n)$. A good reference about the complexity of such operations is the book [Branching Programs and Binary Decision Diagrams](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719789) by Ingo Wegener.

I do not want to go into detail but I think the last step is a little bit more complex than you describe. But I think it can be done in time $O(\log^2 n)$ (i.e. linear to the BDD size) to get the pattern of the 1-inputs and then you need $O(m)$ time to output the intervals.

Comment: What is $m$ in the last line?

Comment: @DaveClarke: The number of intervals for the output (I adopted the notation used in the question).

Comment: Oops. Can one read them off in $O(m)$, given that $m$ is unknown?

Comment: Maybe it is $O(m \log n)$ :) The last step is a little bit tricky. Maybe I edit my answer to give a more detailed description if you are interested in :)

Comment: The whole matter is subtle (and ingenious). My slow Haskell program has the virtue of being more direct.